# Robust Map<Double, sth> in Java

Tags: java, collections

I am looking for a robust Map in Java, where the key lookup would take into account that Double has a limited precision (something around 1e-15 or 1e-16). Where could I find such a thing?

EDIT: Following Jon's advice I think it would make sense to define equivalence. One idea would be to center these at numbers rounded to 15 most relevant decimal digits. Other numbers would be rounded (in any consistent way - the fastest to implement). Would this make sense? What would be the best implementation?

Comment: a key of double? really?

Comment: You need to be more precise in your requirements. In particular, if you're looking for something like "approximate equivalence" that ends up being tricky, as maps assume that if A and B are equal, and B and C are equal, then A and C must be equal too. That doesn't work well with approximate equivalence.

Comment: By 'robust' I guess you want two keys that are within 1e-15 or each or so to be treated as the same key?

Comment: @Jon: I believe it's called transitivity (equivalence relations).

Comment: @MitchWheat, I am trying to cache function invocations.

Comment: how about storing in a sorted list and using binary search?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think you are right. Please see edit to my question.

Comment: @MitchWheat, wouldn't it be functionally identical but slower than using a TreeMap as suggested by AlexR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO The best approach is to normalise the values before adding or looking up values. e.g. by using rounding.

BTW: You can use TDoubleObjectHashMap which support custom hash strategies and uses primitive double keys.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you to use TreeMap and implement your own custom comparator that compares 2 double values taking into account the required precision.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure what you need it for, but you can implement a wrapper around Double and override its `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods to meet your "limited precision" lookup. Therefore any Map implementation will be robust, because it relies on `hashCode()` an `equals()` for key lookup.

Of course, your map will be in a form `Map<DoubleWrapper, smth>`.

Comment: How do I know which Double my key is "close" to without comparing it against every double already in the map?

Comment: Your hashCode() function should return same hash code for all Doubles that are "close". Also equals() should say true for those "close" Doubles. No need to compare all Doubles in the map.

Comment: No doubt it could, but it is not as easy as it seems due to the transitivity property noted by Jon Skeet and Mitch Wheat in the comments.

Comment: Do not forget to cater for `NaN`!

Comment: "close"-ness can be covered by spliting Double domain into bins (e.g. [1.1,1.2) = 1.1, [1.2, 1.3) = 1.2 etc., of course, with required precision).

Answer (score 0):

Summing up answers and comments above, I ended up with the following wrapper (which probably doesn't handle NaN atm):

```
public static class DoubleWrapper {
    private static final int PRECISION = 15;
    private final Double roundedValue;

    public DoubleWrapper(double value) {
        final double d = Math.ceil(Math.log10(value < 0 ? -value: value));
        final int power = PRECISION - (int) d;

        final double magnitude = Math.pow(10, power);
        final long shifted = Math.round(value*magnitude);
        roundedValue = shifted/magnitude;

    }

    public double getDouble() {
        return roundedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return roundedValue.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return roundedValue.hashCode();
    }
}
```